# If G is a tree and $p_1,\ldots,p_n,q_1,\ldots,q_{n+1} $are points of it,how to prove the identity?

Tags: graph-theory

$\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}d(p_i,p_j)+\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n+1}d(q_i,q_j)\leq\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}d(p_i,q_j)$

Comment: Please explain a little more your problem. In particular what is $d$? What are your thoughts on this problem? What have you tried?

Comment: the $d(p_i,p_j)$ means the length of the shorest path between the points $p_i$ and $p_j$, I'm totally confused.I don't know the key point of the inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start for you (only partial, since this seems like homework) :

Let $P = \{p_1, \ldots p_n\}$ and $Q = \{q_1, \ldots, q_{n+1}\}$.

Consider any $p_i, p_j \in P$. Note that of course, $d(p_i, p_j)$ is included in the left-hand sum.
The unique path, call it $U$, between $p_i, p_j$ has only two ways to go : either $U$ includes a vertex from $Q$, or it doesn't.

We can argue that in both cases, $d(p_i, p_j)$ is included in the right-hand sum.
So basically, every path considered on the left has to be considered on the right.
If there is some $q_k$ from $Q$ in $U$, then the right-hand sum includes both
$d(p_i, q_k)$ and $d(p_j, q_k)$, which sum up to $d(p_i, p_j)$.

If $U$ has no vertex from $Q$, then consider any $q_h \in Q$.  Now, since you have a tree, the paths between $p_i, q_h$ and $p_j, q_h$ have to include every edge from $U$ at least once (or otherwise you get a cycle - I suggest drawing it to see why).  So we can deduce that the right-hand sum includes $d(p_i, p_j)$.

So that's a start.  Now, you also have to argue that paths between $Q$ vertex pairs (eg $q_i, q_j$) are also counted by the right-hand sum.  But you can apply a very similar reasoning and this should be enough to help you solve this problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have find a solution about this problem. You can consider how many times a given edge e is counted on each of two sides.Then you'll find the left side is always no more than the  right side.